# Word was unable to read this document. It may be corrupt

Tags: c#, asp.net

`Word was unable to read this document. It may be corrupt`

I am facing this error on server when want to open word file in C# but it works fine on my local machine. I have given all permission to the word file on server and the word file is also not corrupted. But still facing this error.  Please help.

Comment: Do you have the same version of word on your server as on your machine?  Have you tried to open it on the server manually?

Comment: yes i an using the same version. paddy

Comment: Back to the other question then - is this error coming up when you try to open the file manually by double-clicking it? Or when you try to open it in C#? If you get the error opening Word, the file is probably legitimately corrupt. If it's from C#, can we see the code?

Comment: Probably an html file with a .doc extension.

Comment: tim-copenhaver: This error comes when i try to open it in C#. the code is mentioned as below:-

Comment: byte[] original = File.ReadAllBytes(templatePath);using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
stream.Write(original, 0, original.Length);
wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object file = templatePath;
object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object genContractFile = outPath;
object start1 = 0;
object end1 = 0;
object savechanges = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document WordAppdoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);// error comes at this line

Answer (score 0):

If your server has Office 2003 installed, make sure you install Service Pack 3. There was an issue several years ago related to this error, but I believe it was fixed in SP2.

Also, if your file name ends with ".docx" instead of ".doc", it can only be opened in Office 2007 or newer. If you need to edit it in 2003 or older, you have two options. First, on your machine, you can open the document and go to File > Save As to save it as a Word 97-2003 document. Second, you could install the [Office Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3) on the server to enable it to open docx documents.

Comment: I have office 2010 installed on my server and the document is .docx.